# PDO: Update does not work, no error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, pdo

time for a little mystery:
I got this Query:

```
$stmt = 'update wp_term_relationships set term_taxonomy_id = :newID '.
        'where term_taxonomy_id= :oldID and object_id = :postID';
self::$stmtSetNewID = self::$dataBase->prepareStatement($stmt);
[...]
self::$stmtSetNewID->bindParam(':oldID', $oldCatID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
self::$stmtSetNewID->bindParam(':newID', $newCatID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
self::$stmtSetNewID->bindParam(':postID', $postID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result = self::$stmtSetNewID->execute();
$rowCount = self::$stmtSetNewID->rowCount();
echo $rowCount;
```

I tried setting the error level

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and output a possible error

```
var_dump(self::$stmtSetNewID->errorInfo());
```

and output the count of the affected rows (at the end of the code above).
No error, no warning, nothing. `rowCount()` returns 1, but the values in the database keep unchanged.

For me, it looks like the PDO / Database is saying everything worked, but it **didnt**!

I am frustrated as hell and would appreciate every hint! Thank you!

UPDATE:

```
echo "\nPostID: $postID | oldID: $oldCatID ".
     "| newID: $newCatID | rowCount: $rowCount\n<br/>\n";
```

the outputed values are correct, `$rowCount` is 1:

```
PostID: 5432 | oldID: 3 | newID: 32 | rowCount: 1
PostID: 5435 | oldID: 3 | newID: 8 | rowCount: 1
```

Comment: Are you sure the query doesnt update?Maybe it updates with an identical value.

Comment: @Mihai unfortunately i am sure, see the post update.

Comment: Does postID match the expected row? Try removing the check for oldID match. Likely its not required.

Comment: @Anthony when i execute the query with the outputed values in phpMyAdmin, everything works just fine. So yes, it does match. Otherwise it wouldn't tell me a rowCount of 1, right?

Comment: **BASIC DEBUGGING** hardcode variables

Comment: Got it! Sorry for bothering you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, got it. Sorry for wasting your time on my stupidity. As the script says, the updates were executed without errors. But i updated the post after that in my script and this update overwrote my fresh set category.